# Using Wildcards for Directories in Window's copy Command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wildcard

So I am trying to create a batch file to automatically import SSL certificates into the Java keystore, cacerts.  I'm trying to copy all the .crt files into:

C:\Program Files\Java\jre*\lib\security

This way I can then use keytool to import them.  The issue is that the copy command won't let me use jre* to specify the jre directory, and then version.  I want to make the batch so that it will work across multiple PCs with the Java install at C:\Program Files\Java (the default directory), but across multiple versions of the Java jre.

Thanks!

Comment: Err, yes. And what is your question? Please provide a [mcve] with an exact description in which way the code is failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards like `*` and `?` can only be used for the very last element of a path.

You may use the following work-around to achieve what you want (assuming there is only one matching directory):

- in command prompt (`cmd`):

  ```cmd
  for /D %D in ("C:\Program Files\Java\jre*") do @set "FOUNDDIR=%~fD\lib\security"
  echo Found directory: "%FOUNDDIR%"
  ```
- within a batch file:

  ```cmd
  for /D %%D in ("C:\Program Files\Java\jre*") do set "FOUNDDIR=%%~fD\lib\security"
  echo Found directory: "%FOUNDDIR%"
  ```